# facing problem for loading user control from pagemethod

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ascx

i have one user control and one aspx page. with the help of jquery i trigger a page method in my aspx file and which will load the user control from the static method. but i am getting error....so i need help please.

my aspx code behind

---

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
public static string GetOrders(string customerId)
{
    //System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceWarning("In GetOrders");
    //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
    Page page = new Page();
    CustomerOrders ctl = (CustomerOrders)page.LoadControl("CustomerOrders.ascx");
    ctl.CustomerId = customerId;
    page.Controls.Add(ctl);
    System.IO.StringWriter writer = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(page, writer, false);
    string output = writer.ToString();
    writer.Close();
    return output;
}
```

the error message i am getting

**The type or namespace name 'CustomerOrders' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

please give me the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you're putting in the full path to your control. Using the `~/` will resolve the root of your application.

```
CustomerOrders ctl = 
    page.LoadControl("~/The/Full/Path/CustomerOrders.ascx") as CustomerOrders;
```

Comment: both aspx and ascx are in same folder under root. then why should i mention full path.